# Building an XML editor in java and RichFaces

Tags: java, xml, richfaces

I'm building an XML editor using the above technologies.  In essence, I want to read in a whole XML file to a java object, and refer using this object to each element in the XML node tree (grouped into entries) to display the content locked, have separate padlocks for the user to click to 'unlock' an entry allow overwriting of the data, and to submit this entry.  'Add entry', 'Duplicate entry', 'Delete entry' are also functions I'd like to add.

I already use dom4j and XPath to access areas of the XML file so some of the work in theory is already done.  Given the above, I was going to use these two together with `inplaceInput`s to allow the user to edit the XML and JSF validators to check the data coming in.

Is this the best way to approach this problem, or is there a more straightforward route than XPathing a whole record?  I started looking at jaxb but I'm new at java and jsf but I've got the feeling I won't be by the end..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use the richfaces tree to show your XML a bit like Internet Explorer does it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using SIMPLE FRAMEWORK API in java.It is dedicated for XML in java and will certainly suit your needs.You can access the entire xml BASED ON NODE,TRESS,CHILD.Morever writing and reading an XML is equally easy by using serializer and persister which will store the values in repsective setters and gettters.